# How are modules in apache 2.2 operated

Tags: apache2.2

By which mechanism is apache module loaded during runtine, or during startup ?Are in that process used mechanisms like interprocess communication ? Is apache actively calling methods in module, or module itself calls apache method, or both.

For example, get request commes to apache and mod_spnego (kerberos authentication) is loaded. How does apache know when to call main function in module code ?

Answer (score 0):

Apache and its modules are written in C. The modules are loaded during the startup, from shared object files (`.so` on Unix, `.dll` on Windows or as [*Dynamic Shared Object*](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/dso.html)s). When building the Apache HTTPD, it's also possible to compile the modules statically into the `httpd` binary. Both way, they work from the same process.

> How does Apache know when to call main function in module code?

Take a look at these articles, and see what's said about *Hooks*.

- Apache 2.2, [Converting Modules from Apache 1.3 to Apache 2.0](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/developer/modules.html)

  > The new architecture uses a series of hooks to provide for calling
  >   your functions. These you'll need to add to your module by way of a
  >   new function, `static void register_hooks(void)`. The function is really
  >   reasonably straightforward once you understand what needs to be done.
  >   Each function that needs calling at some stage in the processing of a
  >   request needs to be registered, handlers do not.
- [Developing modules for the Apache HTTP Server 2.4](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/developer/modguide.html)

  > When handling requests in Apache HTTP Server 2.4, the first thing you
  >   will need to do is create a hook into the request handling process. A
  >   hook is essentially a message telling the server that you are willing
  >   to either serve or at least take a glance at certain requests given by
  >   clients. All handlers, whether it's mod_rewrite, mod_authn_*,
  >   mod_proxy and so on, are hooked into specific parts of the request
  >   process. As you are probably aware, modules serve different purposes;
  >   Some are authentication/authorization handlers, others are file or
  >   script handlers while some third modules rewrite URIs or proxies
  >   content.